# windowDidResize protocol swift OSX

Tags: macos, swift, window, protocols

I am creating a program and I would like the UI to change based on the size of the window. I'm looking for some method that is called when the window has been resized. I went to the documentation for windowDidResize, but I cannot get it to work when the window is resized.

```
import SpriteKit
import AppKit
class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate ,NSWindowDelegate{

****   bunch of code   ****


  func windowDidResize (notification: NSNotification) {
    HUDComp.updatePosition(size)
    println("Screen has been resized")
  }
}
```

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherit NSWindowDelegate, the only thing you should do is add observer onto NSNotificationCenter.
Code is here.

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("windowDidResize:"), name: NSWindowDidResizeNotification, object: nil)`

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5 <sup>macOS 11+</sup>

Updated for Xcode 12.2 and macOS Big Sur.

This will call `windowDidResize` when the window's dimensions have changed.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NSWindowDelegate.windowDidResize(_:)), name: NSWindow.didResizeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(view.window?.frame.size as Any)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for swift 5. (showing both delegate and notification, choose one..)

```
  import Cocoa

class ViewController: BaseController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.makeItListenZoom()
    }



    override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.view.window?.delegate = self

    }


    private final func makeItListenZoom(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didResizeNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (n: Notification) in

            print("didresize---")
        }
    }



    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification){
           print("windowDidResize")
       }
}
```